# RequireJS: how to dynamically define/add packages

Tags: javascript, dynamic, module, requirejs

I've got a config for requirejs that is shared with multiple applications. When the app is loaded, the app receives an object with the layout of the app (and various other params). I want to use that object to define modules/packages for the app.

`siteMap = { modules: { "foo": { … }, "bar": { … }, … }, other: "stuff" }`

```
/shared/
  libs/
    bootstrap.js
    jquery.js
    …
  app.js

/$appName/
  foo/
    index.html
    edit.html
    main.js
  bar/
    index.html
    stuff.html
    main.js
  …
```

I imagine there must be a way to add packages that goes something like this:

```
// /shared/app.js
require.config({
  paths: {
    "bootstrap": ["//hosted.bootstrap.js","/shared/libs/bootstrap.js"],
    "jquery":    ["//hosted.jquery.js","/shared/libs/jquery.js"],
    "siteMap":   "//appName.example.com/api/siteMap"
  },
  …
});

require(['jquery','siteMap','bootstrap'], function($,siteMap) {
  for ( var module in siteMap.modules )
  {
    require.config.packages[module] = siteMap.modules[module];
    // OR
    require.addPackage(siteMap.modules[module]);
  }
});
```

Comment: What is supposed to happen as the result of the `addPackage` (or whatever) call?

Comment: @explunit, the package gets added to require and its content gets executed (and is available) as if it were in `app.js`

Comment: does anything need to happen with the .html in those folders, or it just needs to load (for example) foo/main.js?

Comment: @explunit, nothing needs to happen with the html files as far as require is concerned (they're template files to be loaded via ajax). Only foo/main.js should/will matter for require.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could nest another `require()` call to load the additional modules after siteMap tells you what should be loaded. Something like this:

```
require(['jquery','siteMap','bootstrap'], function($,siteMap) {
    // .map assumes modern browser or use of something like es5-shim
    var modulesToLoad = siteMap.modules.map(function(m) { return m + '/main'; } );
    require(modulesToLoad, function() {
        // kick off the rest of app logic
    });
});
```

Comment: Where does the map() method come from in `siteMap.modules.map()`? Also, there's supposed to be a semi-colon at the end of line #2, right?

Comment: What if the loaded modules have an unknown number of dependencies? I'm thinking `require(modulesToLoad, function()` should have params declared in the function constructor. Also, my applogies: I over-simplified siteMap; `siteMap.modules` is actually an object not an array.

Comment: @jacob in that case you could use the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) object and do some duck typing on what comes back. Not sure how to do better than that unless the modules to load are a small number of known things and you do some if...then or case logic